# Extract value between brackets with RegExp

Tags: java, regex

I attempt to extract values between brackets `(` and `)`, before I was managed only to check presence of value. Help me to extract it, please.

```
Pattern pattern;
         pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(.*\\b)");
             Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(node.toString());
             if (matcher.find()){
                System.out.println();// here I need to print value that I find between brackets
             }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the brackets in your regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
```

Then you can do:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(node.toString());
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println( matcher.group(1) );
}
```